# Exporting data from Mongo/Cassandra to HDFS using Apache Sqoop

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I have a problem where I have to read data from multiple data sources i.e RDBMS(MYSQL,Oracle) and NOSQL(MongoDb, Cassandra) to HDFS via Hive.(incrementally)

Apache Sqoop works perfectly for RDBMS but it does not work for NOSQL, at-least I was not able to successfully use it, (I tried to use the JDBC driver for Mongo...It was able to connect to Mongo but could not push to HDFS)

IF any one has done any work related to this and can share it , would be really very helpfull

Answer (score 2):

I have used an example from web and able to transfer files from Mongo to HDFS and the other way round. I couldn't gather myself of the exact web page right now. But the program looks like below.

You can get a spark out of this and move on.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.bson.BSONObject;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

import com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

import com.mongodb.hadoop.util.MongoConfigUtil;

public class CopyFromMongodbToHDFS {

    public static class ImportWeblogsFromMongo extends
            Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

        public void map(Object key, BSONObject value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            System.out.println("Key: " + key);
            System.out.println("Value: " + value);
            String md5 = value.get("md5").toString();
            String url = value.get("url").toString();
            String date = value.get("date").toString();
            String time = value.get("time").toString();
            String ip = value.get("ip").toString();
            String output = "\t" + url + "\t" + date + "\t" + time + "\t" + ip;
            context.write(new Text(md5), new Text(output));

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        MongoConfigUtil.setInputURI(conf,
                "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test.mylogs");

        System.out.println("Configuration: " + conf);

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Job job = new Job(conf, "Mongo Import");

        Path out = new Path("/user/cloudera/test1/logs.txt");

        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);

        job.setJarByClass(CopyFromMongodbToHDFS.class);
        job.setMapperClass(ImportWeblogsFromMongo.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(ObjectId.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(BSONObject.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(MongoInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of mongoDB create a mongodump of the collection you want to export to HDFS.

> cd < /dir_name >
>
> mongodump -h < IP_address > -d < db_name > -c < collection_name >

This creates a dump is .bson format, eg "file.bson" . To convert to .json format.
The file.bson will be stored by default in "dump" folder in your specified < dir_name >.

> bsondump file.bson > file.json

copy the file to HDFS using  "copyFromLocal".