# Extract data from MongoDB with Sqoop to write on HDFS?

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop, nosql

I am concerning about extracting data from MongoDB where my application transact most of the data from MongoDB.

I have worked on sqoop to extract data and found RDBMS gel up with HDFS via sqoop. However, no clear direction found to extract data from NoSQL DB with sqoop to dump it over HDFS for big chunk of data processing? 
Please share your suggestions and investigations.

I have extracted static information and data transactions from MySQL. Simply, used sqoop to store data in HDFS and processed the data. Now, I have some live transactions of 1million unique emailIDs per day which data modelled into MongoDB. I need to move data from mongoDB to HDFS for processing/ETL. How can I achieve this goal using Sqoop. I know I can schedule my task but what should be the best approach to take out data from mongoDB via sqoop.

Consider 5DN cluster with 2TB size. Data size varies from 1GB ~ 2GB in peak hours.

Comment: Your question is already so generic. Adding Mongodb/Cassandra will make it more. Add details like sample data, data volume, cluster info.

Comment: I cannot share the data however, I can tell you the sizing in terms of data modelling

Comment: People don't need your data. people need information to understand the usecase.

Comment: lol sure :) . Consider
5 dimensions - city , person name , geo points(lat/long) , appvitals, emailID 
2 measures : data aggragaration on Numbers , mean value of person Vitals

unique emailID count: 10M.
Cluster info: 5DN, 
mongoDB: contains cardinality for now.

Comment: you did not get my point. I don't need column info. I just want to share your usecase. For example : Is it some transaction data? You need to move data daily from mongodb to hdfs or is it a one-time activity. What do you  mean by big chunk of data - GBs, TBs, or more? Answer can not be generic for all NoSQL databases. You clubbed MongoDB/Cassandra in your title. I hope you got my point

Comment: Do you really think just reading your question(_in current state_) people will tell you tools and all..:D

Comment: Add these information to the question so that others can help you too. Add MongoDB, Hadoop, Sqoop version too if possible. People like to answer question with all the details within..:)

Comment: yes sure. Actually scheduling should be hourly basis. Because data belongs to transactions per hour. and unique IDs  per day is in millions. Sqoop support data extraction from RDBMS where static mappings can be extracted. However, huge number of transactions is question to crack from mongoDB

Comment: ok let me elaborate the problem. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25465899/exporting-data-from-mongo-cassandra-to-hdfs-using-apache-sqoop

Answer (score 4):

Sqoop is applied to import data only from relational databases. There are other ways to get data from mongo to Hadoop.

eg: https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/hadoop/

Or else you can use any data flow management tools like Nifi or Streamsets and get data from mongo in realtime.